# automated way for choosing browser version for end-to-end testing?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, docker, version

I am trying to set up a docker container for browser based automated end-to-end testing. The container is based on ubuntu:latest, and I install selenium using pip. However the firefox version in ubuntu is not supported by the newest selenium.

The straightforward solution is to pin the firefox version to an older one, and revise the versions from time to time.

However it is time consuming and might mean too old versions.

Is there an automated way to figure out the latest versions working together, and build a docker image from them?

Suggestions for attacking the problem from another angle are also welcome.

Comment: Did you try the pre-built images: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium ? I am just curious why are you trying to build image by hand.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am trying to set up the full build and test environment, which contains selenium, firefox, chrome, and a host of dependencies for the project. I am doing this to cut down build time.
As I see the the images there for selenium grid nodes, and no image with both of the browsers.

Comment: I think you would be better off using the selenium images & creating a separate container to hold your application (which can then be linked with the selenium ones). This means that all of the work of building the selenium images is done for you & you only have to focus on your own application.